# Zoom only content and not nav bar in jquery

Tags: jquery, android, html, mobile

Hey guys im trying to make it so when someone zooms in on my jquery mobile site it doesn't mess up the nav bar and only zooms the content, is this possible? Right now when i try to zoom in the nav bar gets all squished. thanks :) This is my nav bar:

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <a href="webpage.html" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <a href="index.html"  data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm totally new on jQuery but you can try using percentages instead of fixed values ​​of size in the style of your mobile site.

PS. Sorry for my English.